# How to do namespacing correctly in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to add to my Rails5 app some environment related policies and I'f like to structure them as follow.

```
app
|_ policies
      |_ development
            |_  policy_x.rb
      |_ production
            |_  policy_x.rb
      |_ test
            |_  policy_x.rb



Class Policies::Development::PolicyX
end
```

and so on ...

Then I call the policy I need in an initializer as such

```
MYPOLICY = Policies::Development::PolicyX
```

However, when I try so I get `NameError: uninitialized constant Policies`.

Am I missing anything here?

UPDATE1

using the same structure I have also defined my class as follows

```
module Policies
  module Development
    class PolicyX
    end
  end
end

module Policies
  module Test
    class PolicyX
    end
  end
end

module Policies
  module Production
    class PolicyX
    end
  end
end
```

but still getting the same error.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show how you define `policy_x` and how you try to call it?

Comment: The definition is above. Not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: This seems like a configuration, are you sure you don't want to add them to `config/environments/<env>.rb`? The benefit here is that you can load them based on the current environment with no extra hassle.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That is correct but for some specs, I need to use the Production policy (and not the Test one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Class / file / folder name convention**

Rails has a number of conventions on how you should define classes and file names. For example, a class named PolicyX should reside inside a file named policy_x.rb.

Same goes for modules and folder structures.

If you don't follow this standard conventions, Rails won't be able to load your classes.

**Auto load paths**

By default, Rails looks into all folders found under `app/`

```
app/assets
app/channels
app/controllers
app/controllers/concerns
app/helpers
app/jobs
app/mailers
app/models
app/models/concerns
app/policies
```

While Rails searches `app/policies`, it finds no `Policies` module in there that satisfies the naming and hierarchy conventions. For this to happen, your folder structure would have to be

```
app  
  policies  
    policies  
      development
        policy_x.rb
```

...which obviously looks weird.

You can fix this in three different ways:
a) alter your folder structure and/or module hierarchy to comply with Rails's conventions
b) change `Policies::Development::XPolicy` to `Development::XPolicy`
c) add `app` to `autoload_paths`. By looking directly into `app/`, Rails will be able to find the `policies` folder.

```
# application.rb
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app)
```

---

PS: Rails uses the `underscore` method on a module or class name to figure out what file to load.

```
2.3.0 :001 > 'PolicyX'.underscore
 => "policy_x"
```

Comment: Please, see UPDATE1

Comment: as you can see above, the PolicyX class is inside the `policy_x.rb` file

Comment: Thanks. I ended up by keeping the same folder structure bur renaming the classes as `Development::XPolicy`, `Development::YPolicy` and so on.